# Retrieve specific information from json file in angularjs using controllers and routeParams

Tags: html, angularjs, controller, route-provider

I have this json file

```
 [{
        "name": "China",
        "continent": "Asia",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "UK",
        "continent": "Europe",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Germany",
        "continent": "Europe",
        "id": 3
      }]
```

And I've got these two controllers:

```
 countryApp.controller('CountryListCtrl', function($scope, countries) {
            countries.list(function(countries) {
                $scope.countries = countries;
            });
        });

        countryApp.controller('CountriesDetailCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, countries) {
            countries.find($routeParams.countryId, function(country) {
                $scope.country = country;
            });
        });
```

I'm trying to return only the information of countries that are situated in Europe so I wrote this controller:

```
countryApp.controller('ContinentCtrl', function($scope, countries) {
            countries.list(function(countries) {
                if (country.continent = "Europe") {
                    $scope.country = country;
                }
            });
        });
```

However, I'm not entirely sure how to return it and display using the routeProvider and I don't really follow the explanation given by the documentation. Can someone explain how this would be done for me?

To return the entire list I do:

```
countryApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'country-list.html',
                controller: 'CountryListCtrl'
            }).
            when('/Europe', {
                templateUrl: 'country-list.html',
                controller: 'ContinentCtrl'
            });
});
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you have wrong compare operator, should be '==', like this: if (country.continent == "Europe")

Comment: What is countries here?

Comment: it refers to the countries in the countries.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like ,

```
countryApp.controller('ContinentCtrl', function($scope, countries, $routeParams) {
        countries.list(function(countries) {
          for (var i=0; i < countries.length; i++) {
               if (countries[i].continent == $routeParams.continent) {
                   $scope.countries.push (countries[i]);
               }
            }
        });
    });
```

and in your routing file,

```
countryApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'country-list.html',
            controller: 'CountryListCtrl'
        }).
        when('continents/:continent', {
            templateUrl: 'country-list.html',
            controller: 'ContinentCtrl'
        });
});
```

Comment: Understood. In the controller you presented though there is no indication of what "country" is, so shouldn't it be countries.list(function(country) ?

This is returning all countries regardless of continent at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this way as well simple plain javascript.

```
countryApp.controller('ContinentCtrl', function ($scope, countries) {
       var europeanCountries = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {

           if (countries[i].continent === "Europe") {

               europeanCountries.push(countries[i]);

           }
       }
   });
```